# How to hide bootstrap 2 tool tip after click event

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have to use bootstrap 2.

I have drop down.

```
<select class="populate payment_locations required span12  ng-valid ng-dirty" data-ng-model="payment.location_0" id="location_0" name="location[]" style="">
<option value="">Locations</option>
<option value="2">Texas Childrens Hospital</option>
</select>
```

After bootstrap css & select2 js calling drop down convert in div with span.

After then i have click button then added some attribute `"data-placement": "top", "rel":"tooltip", "data-toggle": "tooltip", "data-trigger":"Click", "data-original-title": "Select Location"` in div.

```
<div class="select2-container populate payment_locations required" id="s2id_location" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="Click" data-original-title="Select Location">
    <a class="select2-choice" onclick="return false;" href="#" tabindex="-1">
        <span>Locations</span>
        <abbr style="display:none;" class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
    </a>
    <div class="select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active select2-offscreen" style="display: block;">
        <div class="select2-search">
            <input type="text" class="select2-input" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <ul class="select2-results"></ul>
    </div>
    <label class="error valid"><i class="glyphicon-remove"></i></label>
</div>

$( ".payment_locations" ).click(function() {
    $(this).find("div.select2-container")
    .attr({ "data-placement": "top", "rel":"tooltip", "data-toggle": "tooltip", "data-trigger":"Click", "data-original-title": "Select Location" })
    .tooltip('show');


    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".select2-container").tooltip('show');
    }, 10);
});
```

and tool tip appear in top side of drop down and also appear in mouse over and disappear after mouse out.

Above the functionality is working fine but i want to be tool tip hide after click event on drop down.

I have all ready set "data-trigger":"Click" in div after clicking on button.

I want to be tool tip hide after click event on drop down. Please help

Comment: Can you perhaps make a jsfiddle or bootply.com demo?